# Able to put needed path into @INC by coding BEGIN block, but still cannot "use win32::Clipboard;"

Tags: perl, perl-module

My computer is running Windows 7. About a week ago I downloaded and installed Strawberry Perl 5.18.2.2 (64bit) for Windows XP or higher. I had no problem running this new version until I tried to include "use win32::Clipboard;".

The module Clipboard.pm was part of that recent download and is located on my computer at C:\strawberry\win32\Clipboard\Clipboard.pm. Note that in this full path all letters are lower case except for the three instances of "C".

If I print out the existing contents of @INC, the result is these three directories:
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib
C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib
C:/strawberry/perl/lib

Since "C:/strawberry/win32/Clipboard" was not in the original "@INC", I knew that I had to add that directory in order to "Use win32::Clipboard;" and so I employed the "BEGIN" command on the second line of this simple program in order to do that.

```
#!C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl - w
BEGIN {unshift @INC, "C:/strawberry/win32/Clipboard"}
use strict;
foreach (@INC)
{
   print "$_\n";
}
<STDIN>;
```

This simple program runs without error and does move the path "C:/strawberry/win32/Clipboard" into @INC as proved by printing out the contents of @INC after the BEGIN command, which yields this:
C:/strawberry/win32/Clipboard
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib
C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib
C:/strawberry/perl/lib

Since I had managed to get "C:/strawberry/win32/Clipboard" into @INC, I thought that I could now "use win32::Clipboard;" and so I added that line to the program to make this new version:

```
#!C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl - w
BEGIN {unshift @INC, "C:/strawberry/win32/Clipboard"}
use Win32::Clipboard; # NOTE that in this line I have also tried "use Win32::Clipboard::Clipboard;" and "use Clipboard::Clipboard;" without success.
use strict;
foreach (@INC)
{
  print "$_\n";
}
<STDIN>;
```

Adding the new line, "use Win32::Clipboard;", caused this error when I ran the program.

"Can't locate Win32/Clipboard.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Win32::Clipboard module) (@INC contains: C:/strawberry/win32/Clipboard C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/strawberry/perl/lib .) at print_inc_array.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at print_inc_array1.pl at line 5."

Even though, I have looked at a lot of examples on the Internet that are claimed to be correct ways to do this, none of them work for me. I have not been able to figure out what is wrong with this simple program, whose purpose is only to find out how to code for the module Clipboard.pm so that I can then code that module in practical programs. Again, I have tried changing the "use" line to "use Win32::Clipboard::Clipboard;" and to "use Clipboard::Clipboard;" without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Reef Alive

Comment: Have you tried to include the path `C:/strawberry/`?

Answer (score 1):

When you say `use Win32::Clipboard;` Perl tries to locate `Win32\Clipboard.pm` in one of the directories in `@INC`.  Since you added `C:/strawberry/win32/Clipboard` to `@INC`, it will try to load `C:\strawberry\win32\Clipboard\Win32\Clipboard.pm`.  But that file doesn't exist; it's `C:\strawberry\win32\Clipboard\Clipboard.pm` instead.  So Perl can't find the file.

But [Win32::Clipboard](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Clipboard) is an XS module, meaning that it contains code that must be compiled by a C compiler before it can be used.  The directory layout you mention suggests that you just unpacked the archive.  That won't work; you need to compile the XS code.

The easiest way to compile the XS code and install the module in the proper path is to use the `cpan` command that comes with Strawberry Perl.  Just type

```
cpan Win32::Clipboard
```

at a command prompt.